# How to implement bignum in Scheme given the following grammar?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, bignum

I think Scheme has a built-in type Bignum for handling arbitrarily large numbers, but if I want to implement it myself how would I do it?

If I am not mistaken it has the following grammar:
|n| = () when n=0
|n| = (r . |q|) where n=qN+r, 0<=r

```
N = base
r = remainder
q = quotient
```

*E.g. When base N=16, |33| = (1 2) wher 1 is a remainder, 2 is a    quotient.*

PS: Using bignum implementation how could I go to the next number (successor) and to the previous number (predecessor), such that `successor |n| = |n+1|` and `predecessor |n+1| = |n|`

Comment: Your grammar is incorrect, though it points in the right direction. And a proper answer to your question requires a book, not a paragraph or three on Stack Overflow. The canonical description of big-integer arithmetic is in Knuth's AoCPv2. Or if you prefer, I did a seven-part series (with code in Scheme) at my blog last summer; see my profile for the url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in luck. The question is a classic. Andre van Meulebrock has written an excellent series of articles on bignums (representation and related algorithms). The article contains runnable Scheme code, so do experiment with his code.

Head over the archives of MacTech:

http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.08/08.03/BigNums/index.html